# How will Google email markup support application deeplinking?

Tags: google-schemas

Reading through the Google email markup documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview) I found not information on how it is possible to deeplink into a native application.

Since an email contains LD+JSON and contains the URL, why can't the schema not support a native deep-link into the Android or iOS app?

I would have thought that this is the most obvious use-case where one-click actionable content makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the JSON-LD example for [EntryPoint](http://schema.org/EntryPoint) on Schema.org you'll notice that it allows `android-app://` and other types of deep links which is a very explicit way of providing deep links for each platform:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Restaurant",
  "name": "Tartine Bakery",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "target": [
      "http://www.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
      {
        "@type": "EntryPoint",
        "urlTemplate": "http://api.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
        "contentType": "application/json+ld"
      },
      "android-app://com.urbanspoon/http/www.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
      {
        "@type": "EntryPoint",
        "urlTemplate": "urbanspoon://r/6/92204",
        "application": {
          "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
          "@id": "284708449",
          "name": "Urbanspoon iPhone & iPad App",
          "operatingSystem": "iOS"
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "EntryPoint",
        "urlTemplate": "urbanspoon://r/6/92204",
        "application": {
          "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
          "@id": "5b23b738-bb64-4829-9296-5bcb59bb0d2d",
          "name": "Windows Phone App",
          "operatingSystem": "Windows Phone 8"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Eventually, once deep linking is baked into all of Google's products, these mappings could be crawled from your webpage and the correct links automatically applied regardless of whether you're view a Highlight in Gmail on Chrome or one of the native mobile apps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am not sure that it is good to rely on Google to crawl a web-page as there will be scenarios where content has gone live before Google was able to crawl it which would then ruin the user experience. Would be great if the Google code examples would highlight the native app deeplink concerns though.

Comment: True. Putting all the deep links in the email is the safest approach. I'll see what I can do to get this clarified in the docs.

Comment: A good thing would be to allow a object containing links for the multiple cases. For example, if the email is opened in an Android device, it might try to open the specific app (if registered) or fall back to a website.